# The proportion of population covered by created isochrones in QGIS

Tags: qgis, population, isochrone

I created isochrones using Iso-Area as polygons algorithm is QGIS. I would like to calculate the proportion of the population covered by the created isochrones. Is there any tool in QGIS to do this?

Comment: Depends on the population data you've got.

Comment: Use zonal statistics, see e.g. here for a similar problem (population as raster layer, overlay with a polygon): https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382557/88814

Comment: Maybe this http://www.iso4app.com/index.jsp can help you

Comment: @Erik I have not collected the data yet. which type of population data do I need for this analysis?

Comment: I'd go with Pop-density, then you can intersect and calculate the approx. pop based on the area of the intersections.